# Need a responsive datepicker rather than pickadate.js

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker, responsive-design

I need a responsive date picker for travel site. I've tried lots of Google searches but can't find any responsive date picker except pickadate.js but I want to show two months at a time...

I also tried to make the jQueryUI date picker responsive like:

```
 @media (max-width: 480px) {    
   #ui-datepicker-div{ width:70%!important;}
  .ui-datepicker-multi, .ui-datepicker-group {float: none!important;}
  .ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group{width:100%!important;}
}
```

but the problem is the calender open in up direction; see the attached photo

[image: in iphone the calender open in up direction]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this,

[jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox)

OR

[jQuery UI's Datepicker Styled for mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/)

Answer (score 5):

```
@media (max-width: 622px) and (min-width: 1px){    
#ui-datepicker-div{ width:90%!important;}.ui-datepicker-multi, .ui-datepicker-group {float: none!important;}   .ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group{width:100%!important;}   }@media only screen and (max-width: 622px) and (min-width: 1px) {  .ui-datepicker-group-last{ display:none!important;  }}
```

Comment: can you provide an explanation regarding your code and the changes you've made?