# Code error : body not closing and menu going over 100% width

Tags: jquery, html, css, tags, width

I have 2 problems with a website I'm working on. The /body tag appears to have an error in Web Expression 4 and I can't seem to find why. Plus the menu's width goes over the rest of the page wich is not supposed to scroll horizontally. All divs look like they're closed so as it's making me crazy I hope you'll be able to help me ! Here is the html :

```
<body>
   <div class="parallax"> 
      <div id="menu">
         <ul>
            <script>
               $('#menu li')
               .mouseover(function() {
               $(this).addClass('animated flash');})
               .mouseout(function() {
                  $(this).removeClass('animated flash');
                });
            </script> 
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="newsmenu" href="#news">Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">Mariepskop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">Hoedspruit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script>
           $( function() {
           $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
            });
      </script>
      <div class="date">
         <p>Arrival:<a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a>   
          <input type="text"class="datepicker"></p>
          <p></p>
          <p>Departure:&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
          <p><button class="button1">CHECK AVAILABILITY</button></p>
          <script> $('.button1')
              .mouseover(function() {
                   $(this).addClass('animated pulse');})
                   .mouseout(function(){
                       $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');});
          </script>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="parallax2">
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">4 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro4.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">5 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">6 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro6.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">7 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro7.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">8 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro8.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">9 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro9.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">10 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro10.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br></br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)"></span> 

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
<div class="textcontainer">
<p>
<center>
<span class="hot">WELCOME TO MARIEPSKOP VIEW CHALETS</span>
</center> </p>`
<p><center><span class="basictext">Located between the famous 
<span class="basiceffect">Blyde River Canyon</span> and the 
<span class="basiceffect">Kruger National Park(Orpen Gate)</span>,
<p>our lodge offers the best situation in the region. 
Halfway from all the  activites around, </p>
<p>experience the very best of South Africa and relax in our 
cosy  rooms</p>   </span></center></p>
</div>                      
<div class=map>
/* Theres a IFRAME tag here with google map styled width 100% border:0 and frameborder:0 but I cant add the four saces before it so I deleted it from here */

   <div class="parallax"></div>
   </body>
```

And here is the CSS :

```
body, html {
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
}
.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
.parallax2 {
    height:2000px;
    background-color:#9f7f68;
    z-index:2;
}

#menu {
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    left:0%;
    margin:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    z-index:999;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menu ul {
    max-width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#menu li a {
    padding: 14px 16px;
    display: block;
    margin:2%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #9f7f68;
    color:#000;

}

.active {
    font-size:25px;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#593620;
}

/* -------------------SLIDESHOW NOW--------------------------- */
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
/* ---------------------FORM-----------------------*/
.date {
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 80%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width:10%;
    height:35%;
    padding:2%;
}
.date:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}




}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #ccb8a0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    padding: 3PX;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}
.button1:hover {
    background-color: #ccb8a0;
    color: white;
}





/*  ------------------------------------TEXT--------------------------------- */
.textcontainer {
    width:100%;
    padding:3%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.hot {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:25px;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.basictext {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;

}
.basiceffect
{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;

}
.map {
    width:100%;
}
```

**EDIT :**
/body problem looks to be fixed now but I still have the problem with menu width :
[This is the problem i'm trying to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftwit.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this corrected html as you missing two closing divs:

Updated bellow style for menu issue:

```
.textcontainer {
    width:94%;
    padding:3%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Updated fiddle [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/9k093ufy/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/9k093ufy/1/)

```
<body>
<div class="parallax">


<div id="menu">

<ul><script>
$('#menu li')
.mouseover(function() {
$(this).addClass('animated flash');})
.mouseout(function(){
$(this).removeClass('animated flash');});
</script>

<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="newsmenu" href="#news">Rooms</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Mariepskop</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Hoedspruit</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
$( function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
</script>
<div class="date">
<p>Arrival:<a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>   
<input type="text"class="datepicker"></p>
<p></p>
<p>Departure:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
<p><button class="button1">CHECK AVAILABILITY</button></p>
<script> $('.button1')
.mouseover(function() {
$(this).addClass('animated pulse');})
.mouseout(function(){
$(this).removeClass('animated pulse');});
</script>

</div>
</div>

<div class="parallax2">
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">4 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro4.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">5 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">6 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro6.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">7 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro7.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">8 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro8.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">9 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro9.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">10 / 10</div>
<img src="images/gallery/intro10.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br><br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)"></span> 


</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
<div class="textcontainer">
<p>
<center>
<span class="hot">WELCOME TO MARIEPSKOP VIEW CHALETS</span>
</center> </p>`
<p><center><span class="basictext">Located between the famous 
<span class="basiceffect">Blyde River Canyon</span> and the 
<span class="basiceffect">Kruger National Park(Orpen Gate)</span>,
<p>our lodge offers the best situation in the region. 
Halfway from all the  activites around, </p>
<p>experience the very best of South Africa and relax in our 
cosy  rooms</p>   </span></center></p>
</div>                      
<div class=map>
/* Theres a IFRAME tag here with google map styled width 100% border:0 and frameborder:0 but I cant add the four saces before it so I deleted it from here */

   <div class="parallax"></div>
   </div>   
   </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: This looks like it corrected the /body tag error even though you closed the "map" div at the end after the second "parallax" div wich is not what I wanted but I changed it. Thank you very much ! Just have to correct the Menu width now

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle. so I can check it and correct it

Comment: Or give any live url where I can check it and suggest you solution

Comment: First time i make one if you need me to add the pictures and stuff tell me.

Comment: There's a picture in my first post (the question in itself) I just edited it

Comment: let me check fiddle and find issue

Comment: you can check updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/9k093ufy/1/

Comment: Can you tell me what did you change please ?

Comment: Maybe you can help me with something else : I need the "datepicker" (Jquery.ui plugin) box to resize with the size of window. Instead of it it just goes out of screen if I make make the window smaller. Do you need the Jquery.ui.css or do you have it ?

Comment: You can try responsive datepicker [ref link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864675/need-a-responsive-datepicker-rather-than-pickadate-js)